# Continue/run commands after ssh into VM

Tags: command-line, ssh, terminal, vagrant

I have to take quite a few steps before I get into the file I need to be, which is why I'm trying to set up an alias in my terminal, that gets me to the file by running that alias.

The following steps are needed to arrive where I have to be:

1. `cd Sites`
2. `vagrant ssh`
3. `cd /var/www/miniportal.billetten.dk/logs/`
4. `sudo -s`
5. `cd /etc/apache2/sites-available/`
6. `nano 25-av_miniportal.conf`
7. Edit line 33 in that file (I guess it's possible to jump to that line)

I tried setting up an alias like this, but the problem is that it stops running the rest of the command after I SSH'd into `Vagrant`. if I manually `exit` Vagrant, it continues the command (and of course returns an error, because there is no such folder).

The question is: How do I make sure that everything from step 3 is executed AFTER step 2 is done logging in through SSH?

My ultimate goal is to set up an Apple Automator program that lets me put in a value that gets entered on line 33, but I'm fine with just an alias for now.

Comment: do you want to run that everytime you do `vagrant ssh` or only when vm is initialized (`vagrant up`) ? in first case you would need to create the alias for  3-7 and add to your .bash; in second you can use a script provisioning

Comment: No, I don't want to run it every time I do `vagrant ssh`, since I also have to do some other stuff in there (rarely, but it happens). I figured out it's not possible to send commands to Vagrant from my own machine, so I have now set up an action I manually run after I SSH into Vagrant. This changes 4 steps into one step, so that's quite the improvement!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know I asked this question a long time ago, but in the meantime I found a solution and forgot I had posted this question.

My alias in my `.zshrc`-file looks like this:

`alias changeCust='ssh -t root@192.168.56.101 "nano +32 /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/25-av_miniportal.conf && service apache2 reload"'`

In other words, it SSHs into vagrant as root (it asks for my password), nanos into a file on line 32 (or whatever line you need), then, when the file is saved, it reloads `apache2` and the changes are applied.

Just use the below one and change the values.

`alias AliasName='ssh -t root@your.ip.addres.here "nano +lineNumber /path/to/file"'`